# How can I get the sum of numbers in an HTML table on a different page that is fetched through Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get the sum of numbers in an HTML table on a different page that is fetched through Ajax?

I have this code with me:

page1 : ajax jquery

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

  <script>
$.ajax({
url: 'page2.html',
datatype: "html",
success : function (data) {

 var s = 0;
  $(data).find("#a tr").each(function(){
  var nam = $(this).find("tr").text();
  var pa = parseInt(nam);
  s+=pa

  });
  $("b").html(s);
  }
  });

  </script>
</head>

<body>
<b></b>
</body>
</html>
```

page2 : HTML

```
<body>

<table id='a' border='2'>
<tr>
<td>510</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
</tr>    
<tr>
<td>8</td>
</tr>    
<tr>
<td>17</td>
</tr>    
<tr>
<td>30</td>
</tr>    
<tr>
<td>31</td>
</tr>    
<tr>
<td>31</td>
</tr>    
</table>

</body>
```

but error :(
How can I do that?

i want Collection  Numbers of Page 2 by jquery

I want to be the result

numbers = 598

but how ?

and thanks

Comment: <<but error>> Which error?

Comment: The total seems to be more than 598.  And what is the error?

Comment: What is the error? What are you seeing? What are you expecting to see instead?

Answer (score 2):

<s>You should be finding `td` instead of `tr`:</s> It doesn't make a difference either way, but I think it is semantically more-appropriate to do this:

```
var s = 0;

$(data).find("#a tr").each(function() {
    var nam = $(this).find("td").text();
    var pa = parseInt(nam);
    s+=pa
});
```

But I don't see why you couldn't just do this:

```
$(data).find("#a tr td").each(function() {
    var nam = $(this).text();
    var pa = parseInt(nam);
    s+=pa
});
```

Also, please explain what the error is and what it is that you're expecting to see.

Comment: @roasted I don't think so. In the scope of the callback for `each`, `this` will point to the current element.

Comment: @roasted - you're wrong, it's inside the scope of the each function, so it references the elements.

Comment: My bad don't see the each loop

Comment: However, it won't solve the problem, as `$('tr').text()` will return exactly the same as `$('tr td').text()`in this case.

Comment: @adeneo Why not? I just tested it on a fiddle and it seemed to work? Let me create another one.

Comment: It work's, but so does selecting the TR's, there is no difference, so that's not the issue.

Comment: @adeneo You're absolutely right. The sum is `629` in both cases. I guess we won't know until OP explains what the error is.